# Backbone.js save model don't cause ajax PUT request on android 2.x

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, cordova

Phonegap + Backbone + jquery mobile.
My Backbone models look like(some code removed)

```
var Purchase = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            name: "",
            desc: "",
            shopping: null,
            price:null,
            quantity:1,
            createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
            modifiedAt: new Date().getTime()
        };
    }
});

var PurchaseList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Purchase,
    comparator: 'name'
});

var ShoppingList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function(){
        return {
            name:"",
            totalPrice: 0,
            createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
            modifiedAt: new Date().getTime(),
            products: new PurchaseList()
        };
    }
});
```

Update purchase logic recalculate totalPrice of ShoppingList

```
save: function(position){

            var data  =  this.$el.find("form").serializeObject();
            var price = parseFloat(data.price);
            var quantity = parseFloat(data.quantity);
            var product = new Purchase(data);
            product.on('invalid', this.showError);

            var shopping = GlobalShopping.findWhere({id: data.shopping});

            if(!isNaN(price) && !isNaN(quantity))
                    shopping.set('totalPrice', shopping.get('totalPrice') + price * quantity);

            if(!isNaN(price))
                    product.set('price', price);
            else
                    product.unset('price');

            if(!isNaN(quantity))
                    product.set('quantity', quantity);

            if(this.model.id){

                    var oldProduct = shopping.get('products').findWhere({id: this.model.id});

                    if(oldProduct.get('price') != null)
                            shopping.set('totalPrice', shopping.get('totalPrice') - oldProduct.get('price') * oldProduct.get('quantity'));

                    product.id = this.model.id;
                    product.save({}, { success: function(){
                                    shopping.get('products').add([product], {merge: true});

                                    shopping.save({}, {success: function(){ // <<<< issue here
                                            window.app_router.navigate('#shopping/' + data.shopping, {replace: true, trigger: true});       
                            }});

                    }});
            } else {
                    shopping.get('products').create(product, {wait: true, success: function(){
                            shopping.save({}, {success: function(){
                                            window.app_router.navigate('#shopping/' + data.shopping, {replace: true, trigger: true});       
                    }});

            }, error: function(model, xhr, options){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(product.toJSON()));
            }});    
            }
     }
```

This code works perfect on android 4.x, but on android 2.x success event firing without PUT request(checked by server logs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is android 2 browser issue. It cache GET, POST and PUT(facepalm) requests.
I'd

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                 cache: false
            });
```

but it's affect only on GET requests.

My final solution is add nonce to the url

```
url: function(){ return "rest_entity + $.now(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Backbone source, a PUT request will only be triggered if the model you are trying to save has an Id. Could you try the following:

```
product.set('id', 1);
product.save();
```

Having a quick glance at your code, I am not sure how you populating your product. Are you first fetching it then trying to re-save it? Anyhow, Backbone will issue a POST if no Id is set and a PUT if the Id property is set. You can change your Id Attribute property like so [Backbone Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute). I would console.log your model in both instances, and make sure the relevant Id property is set.

Strange it works on android 4 on android 2.x and up. Maybe you could provide more code on how product is being set if the above does not head you in the right direction.

Comment: look at 'save' method

Comment: Are you running this app through the browser or are you packaging it up into something like phonegap? If you are running it through the browser, maybe create a simple index and js file that uses $.ajax with method PUT and calls your API so you can view the server log file. Will make an interesting test case. Tried to look at a few issues on the web related to Android 2.X and PUT with no avail.

Comment: I't phonegap application(*.apk). I guess it's some kind of Backbone issue, because first save/update product operation completes success(with PUT request).